# mysql row number count down and dynamic number of row

Tags: mysql, rows, countdown

I believe it can be solve by temp table/stored procedure but in case it can be done by single SQL statement.

Goal: List all row with count down by year, however number of row of each year is different. Row can be order by date

Result Arm to:

```
|-Count Down-|-Date-------|
| 3          | 2013-01-01 | <- Start with number of Row of each year
| 2          | 2013-03-15 |
| 1          | 2013-06-07 |
| 5          | 2014-01-01 | <- Start with number of Row of each year
| 4          | 2014-03-17 |
| 3          | 2014-07-11 |
| 2          | 2014-08-05 |
| 1          | 2014-11-12 |
```

SQL:

```
Select @row_number:=@row_number-1 AS CountDown, Date
FROM table JOIN 
    (Select @row_number:=COUNT(*), year(date) FROM table GROUP BY year(date))
```

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: And the output should be?

Comment: @juergend He showed the desired output.

Comment: I have trouble on assigning the count(*) into @row_number when year changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subquery that gets the count by year needs to return the year, so you can join it with the main table to get the starting number for the countdown. And you need to detect when the year changes, so you need another variable for that.

```
SELECT @row_number := IF(YEAR(d.Date) = @prevYear, @row_number-1, y.c) AS CountDown,
       d.Date, @prevYear := YEAR(d.Date)
FROM (SELECT Date 
      FROM Table1 
      ORDER BY Date) AS d
JOIN 
    (Select count(*) AS c, year(date) AS year
     FROM Table1 
     GROUP BY year(date)) AS y
ON YEAR(d.Date) = y.year
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prevYear := NULL) AS x
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/791f0/4)

Answer (score 0):

You can do the count down using variables (or correlated subqueries).  The following does the count, but the returned data is not in the order you specify:

```
select (@rn := if(@y = year(date), @rn + 1,
                  if(@y := year(date), 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as CountDown, t1.*
from table1 cross join
     (select @y := 0, @rn := 0) vars
order by date desc;
```

That is easily fixed with another subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select (@rn := if(@y = year(date), @rn + 1,
                        if(@y := year(date), 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as CountDown, t1.*
      from table1 cross join
           (select @y := 0, @rn := 0) vars
      order by date desc
     ) t
order by date;
```

Note the complicated expression for assigning `CountDown`.  This expression is setting both variables (`@y` and `@rn`) in a single expression.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `select`.  If you assign these in different expressions, then they might be executed in the wrong order.